# Lua question: Why my program didnt read or didnt set value for argument?

Tags: lua, roblox

The localScript:

```
local s
if game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopCars:FindFirstChild(script.Parent.Name) then
    s = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("ShopCars")
elseif game.ReplicatedStorage.PurchasedCars:FindFirstChild(script.Parent.Name) then
    s = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("PurchasedCars")
end
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.OpenBuyFrame:FireServer(s[script.Parent.Name].Cost.Value, s[script.Parent.Name].Named.Value, s[script.Parent.Name].Owned.Value, script.Parent.Parent.Name)
end)
```

the Script:

```
script.Parent.Parent.OpenBuyFrame.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,cost,name,owned,typeofcar)
    if owned == true then
        script.Parent.BuyFrame.DoYouWant.Text = "Do you want to sell this car?"
        script.Parent.BuyFrame.Yes.Text = "Sell"
    else
        script.Parent.BuyFrame.DoYouWant.Text = "Do you want to buy this car?"
        script.Parent.BuyFrame.Yes.Text = "Buy" 
    end
    script.Parent.BuyFrame.Cost.Text = cost
    script.Parent.BuyFrame.Named.Text = name
    local oldcarimage = script.Parent.BuyFrame:FindFirstChild("ViewportFrame")
    if oldcarimage then
        oldcarimage:Destroy()
    end
    camera = script.Parent[typeofcar][name].ViewportFrame:Clone()
    camera.Parent = script.Parent.BuyFrame
    camera.Size = UDim2.new(0.432, 0,0.401, 0)
    camera.Position = UDim2.new(0.283, 0,0.229, 0)
    script.Parent.BuyFrame.Visible = true
end)
```

I'm dont know how to solve this ploblem.
looks like cost and name value dont set, and its value is nil

Answer (score 0):

ok, script is right, just roblox is lagging